# Can a plastic protector affect heat dissipation in a laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, cooling

I have an HP Pavilion which I have been using since October 2014. The machine is in mint condition and has never dropped/impacted anywhere.

Recently I removed the plastic protectors on the side edges of the screen, replacing them with a slightly stronger plastic and covering the edge on both sides (front and back) with a continuous flap.

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGbro.jpg) | [Rear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAlxb.jpg)

Today I randomly experienced my screen showing magenta lines (horizontal) and the multiple reflections of the windows being shown on the screen, something of [this sort](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_EDFqRcmDYac/TTq8o_Av2JI/AAAAAAAAAgo/v3SES9ECOcY/s1600/photo+5.JPG) and for a few seconds, the screen would go magenta all over.

The problem was miraculously solved all by itself, without a reboot.

Can covering the edges with plastic have something to do with it? (i.e. heat dissipation, etc? I can barely feel the heat even when I touch the right side which has the cathode lamp. Can heated electronics inside the screen do this?

I've torn apart a few LCD screens in the past and the only electronic board inside the screen is the DC-AC inverter for the lamp, which was working fine (the problem was with the pixels). I doubt the electronics inside the screen could overheat that much to cause problems.

Comment: You did something "non-standard" on your screen and experienced a transient problem.  There's really no way for people to factually explain what happened in your case, and a theoretical discussion of what might possibly happen if somebody did something similar would be speculation.  If you could describe a procedure that people could follow to reliably replicate what happened, you would have something for people to work with, but this is too speculative as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a monitor that started to show black lines, and suggestions from one forum were to massage the screen edge nearby.  This actually worked for a while.  I think the theory is that there's dodgy electrical connectivity at the edge of the matrix.  So mechanical stresses at the edge of a display may have a positive or negative effect.  I wouldn't think that it was directly caused by excess heat but possibly the general heat casuses shrinkage of the film and thus a mechanical stress.  I'd get rid of the protector.

Comment: The problem was only temporary, and occurred only for a few minutes, and only once. It was all okay afterwards. What you are talking about is dead pixels which they aren't. I'm concerned about the fact if such plastic can actually encumber heat dissipation to such a level that such havoc starts wreaking up on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some privacy filters on a screen, I wouldn't recommend covering the laptop monitor.

As far as the magenta lines, it could be your [video processor](http://www.rsbandb.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=79360) [is starting to over heat](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/68144-35-lines-laptop-screen).  You may want to adjust your power settings, assuming you haven't already, to put it in balanced or low power mode.

If this doesn't do anything to fix the problem, then you may want to backup your data, and consider purchasing a new laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the info (+1). But regarding GPU overheating vs monitor overheating, I doubt an overheated video card would even produce output on the screen. The output was there, fine, but covered with magenta lines (similar to dead pixels). The duration was too short for me to plug in an HDMI cable and try displaying over an HDTV to check the GPU. And the problem has only occurred once, so I doubt a new laptop would be a good idea.